# How to parse both Date and Time in using gson?

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a json input that contains the following fields (among others):

```
...
leadDate: "2016-01-16",
leadTime: "13:45:22",
...
```

I'm trying to parse this json using Gson library to set them to the following Java attributes:

```
private Date leadDate;
private Time leadTime;
```

but the setDateFormat method doesn't allow me to set both date format and time format without the use of DateFormat constants. And these, as far as I know, doesn't include the formats I need.

What can I do if I have to use Gson?

Comment: Can you affect the API you consume? What you want from GSON is to combine the valeus from two attributes into one property, which it can not do

Comment: What Java version are you using? Java 8?

Comment: I can't affect the format at the moment

Comment: Is your goal to combine both of these fields into one object in Java, or do you want to keep them as separate objects?

Comment: I want to keep them as separate fields. See edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## No Date-Time Types In JSON

JSON lacks any date-time [data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example). So the format and meaning of your Strings is up to you and your data supplier/consumer.

## Use java.time Classes

Avoid the old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java such as java.util.Date/.Calendar. They are notoriously troublesome. In Java 8 and later they have been officially supplanted by the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework.

## Converters

Gson has [converters for serializers/deserializers](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Built-in-Serializers-and-Deserializers) to handle the chore of dehydrating and rehydrating java.time objects. See: [Gson Type Adapters for Common Classes](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-type-adapters-for-common-classes-1). Or consider [writing your own](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization). Such serialization tools would do something like the following.

## Parsing

Your date and time are separate. Start by parsing each as [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) and [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html). Both your String inputs comply with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard defining formats of Strings representing date-time values. That is handy as the java.time classes use this standard as their defaults when parsing or generating such Strings.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( "2016-01-16" );
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse( "13:45:22" );
```

## Time Zone

Both `LocalDate` and `LocalTime` are date-only and time-only respectively, and both lack any time zone or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) information. Such time zone information is critical to making sense of your date-time data. Does your example data mean a quarter until two in the afternoon of Paris, Montreal, or Tokyo? Perhaps you have additional fields of data with this  zone/offset info, or perhaps in your context you can assume the time zone.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
```

Let's apply that time zone to our date-only and time-only to get a full-fledged date-time, an actual moment on the timeline.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( localDate , localTime , zoneId );
```

## String Output

You can output in ISO 8601 compliant string by simply calling [`toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#toString--). Actually, java.time extends the ISO 8601 format by appending the name of the time zone in brackets.

> 2016-01-16T13:45:22-05:00[America/Montreal]

To generate Strings in other formats, search StackOverflow.com for many examples of [java.time.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/package-summary.html) package.

## `Instant`

Generally the best practice is to do your business logic and data storage/exchange all in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). In java.time that means the [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class which represents a moment on the timeline in UTC. We can instantiate an `Instant` object from our `ZonedDateTime`.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant();
```

Answer (score 0):

**java.sql.Date** and **java.sql.Time** have already built-in methods for doing it. Simply read the data from json file and pass it in `valueOf` method like this--

1. In the case of leadDate-
   `Date.valueOf(value of leadDate);`
2. In the case of leadTime-
   `Time.valueOf(value of leadTime);`